# swiftで別storybordからコピー&ペーストしたコードについたコネクト接続の解除

Tags: swift, xcode

swiftで別storybordからコピー&ペーストしたコードについたコネクト接続の解除をするにはコード上の丸をどのようにしたらいいですか？ IF側は表示できません

Comment: 第一文は、なにを話題（主題）にしている文なのか、わかりません。英語と異なり、日本語は主語がなくても文が成立すると、よく言われますが、それは主題を主語として提示していないだけのことで、なにを対象にして語っているのか、明解でなければ、その文は成立していないということになります。高校の現代国語のレベルで、第一文を解析してみると、主題は「コード」か「コネクト接続」のどちらかになりそうですが、どちらかに断定することができません。このようなわかりにくい（というより、わからない）文を書かない、即効薬は、できるだけ一文を短くすることです。第一文は、おそらく５文くらいに分割できそうですね。それと第２文の「IF」とはなんですか？省略語の使用をできるだけ避けるのも、伝わりやすい文を書くテクニックです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**コードエディタと、Storyboardの間のコネクション（Connection）を解除する方法。**

このようにご質問の趣旨を理解させていただいた上で、回答をします。もしそういう趣旨でないのであれば、コメントでお知らせいただくか、質問文を編集して、お書き換えください。

---

コネクション解除の方法を、ふたつ説明します。
最初は、Connections Inspectorを使用します。

接続しているオブジェクト（UILabel、UIImageView、UITableViewなどなど）を選択して、Connections Inspectorを開きます。下図のようにコネクションが表示されますので、✖︎アイコンをクリックして、接続を解除します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

次は右クリック（Controlキー＋クリック）を使ったものです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

接続を解除したいオブジェクトを右クリックすると、Connections Inspectorと同じ小窓が開きますから、それで同様に解除します。

---

以上、接続の解除は、いずれもStoryboard上で行います。接続を行う時、Storyboardとコードエディタのペインを開いて、操作するので、なんとなくコードエディタでも接続解除できそうな気になりますが、それはできないようです。それは考察を加えてみるとわかります。コード上の`@IBOutlet`や`@IBAction`とStoryboardのオブジェクトの接続情報は、プロジェクトのどこに書き込まれて保存されるのか？すこし調べてみます。
Project NavigatorのStoryboard書類を、右クリック（Control + クリック）してプルダウンメニューを出し、「Open as Source Code」を選びます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Storyboard書類の実体が、XML形式のファイルであることがわかります。その一部を抜粋すると……

```
<viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="GestureTest" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        <subviews>
            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" fixedFrame="YES" image="Baseball.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VMj-nc-WUJ">
                <rect key="frame" x="143" y="384" width="129" height="129"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            </imageView>
        </subviews>
        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
    </view>
    <connections>
        <outlet property="imageView" destination="VMj-nc-WUJ" id="6Vr-Aw-kRh"/>
    </connections>
</viewController>
```

`<connections>`タグが含まれ、接続の情報が記述されているのを、見つけることができます。このことから、プロジェクト内の接続の情報は、Storyboard書類に記述され、保存されていることがわかりました。

コードエディタ上で、`@IBOutlet`のプロパティあるいは`@IBAction`のメソッドが接続状態になっているのに、対象となるStoryboard書類がないということがありえないということも、このことからわかります。一見Storyboard書類がないと思えても、探せば見つかるはずです。
探し方はかんたんです。
コードエディタ上の、接続状態を示す◉アイコンを、Command + クリックしてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

小窓に、対象のStoryboard書類と、対になるオブジェクトが表示され、それをクリックすると、Storyboard書類が開きます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます 最後の文のように コード上で接続解除したいです ですが むりのようなので ありがとうございます